# Therefore, in order to properly follow the tutorials, a recent compiler is needed

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Therefore, *in order to properly* follow the tutorials, a recent compiler is needed.

What does above sentence mean?
Are **in order** to and **properly** same?

Comment: It means that reading is not enough: learners must be provided with hands-on experience.

Comment: @DanBron thanx for info

Comment: Could you post the preceding sentence?

Answer (score 1):

It means an older compiler is not acceptable, and you may not have success finishing the tutorials without a recent compiler.

The implied goal here is *follow the tutorials*, and to do it *properly* (meaning correctly.).  The phrase *in order to* is a condition: In order to cut a piece of meat, you need a knife; in order to mail a letter, you need an envelope and a stamp; in order to be comfortable in cold weather, you need a coat.

Incidentally, the phrase *to properly follow* is an example of a [split infinitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive), like the classic "To boldly go where no man has gone before". When you use "to X" where X is a verb, this is an infinitive, and adverbs are not technically supposed to go in between the word "to" and the verb it goes with. If you're writing a newspaper article or a scholarly book or an English class essay, it's incorrect, but in casual conversation it doesn't really matter and most people won't even notice.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence means that a new compiler is required for the tutorials, likely because an older one won't have the correct features.

But no, "in order to" and "properly" are not the same.

In essence, "in order to" here could be phrased as "if you want to." Similarly, "properly" could be rephrased as "accurately" (kind of, at least).

> Therefore, if you want to correctly follow the tutorials, a recent compiler is needed.

"Properly" isn't super important here, and it's used mostly to emphasize the point. "In order to" could probably be comfortably reduced down to "to," but I would be more hesitant making that change.

> Therefore, to follow the tutorials, a recent compiler is needed.